# How can I check if InputStream is sending data or not? (working with GSON)

Tags: java, android, listener, inputstream

I didn't find this question on StackOverflow or maybe I searched with loose keywords.

I use to get an InputSteam normally for JSON files on Internet, this is my main function:

```
    static HttpGet getRequest;
    static HttpResponse getResponse;
    public static InputStream retrieveStream(String url, int timeout) {

getRequest = null;
getResponse = null;

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

try {

    getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);

    final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Log.w("ERROR", "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
        return null;
    }

    HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

    return getResponseEntity.getContent();

} catch (IOException e) {
    getRequest.abort();
    Log.w("ERROR", "Error for URL " + url, e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    getRequest.abort();
    Log.w("ERROR", "Error for URL " + url, e);
}

return null;
    }
```

for the scope of avoiding errors or giving the possibility to the user to cancel the request because Internet is ON but isn't working fine, I would like to make a counter when my app is not receiving data and it's not completed. I know how to do the counter, but, how could I make that type of 'listener'?

I use to continue with this (always Asynchronously):

```
            InputStream source = f.retrieveStream(params[0]);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);

        response = gson.fromJson(reader, Usuario.class);
```

thanks in advance.